# Receiving error messages at random in Google Colab pro -Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, google-colaboratory

I am running a code in Google Colab for training a neural network.

All my scripts have been working just fine, but starting this week, I have been receiving this error:

> RuntimeError: cuDNN error: CUDNN_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED

which seems to occur at random. Sometimes it occurs at the beginning of my script run, say, even before epoch *1*, some other times at epoch 160 or 56 or so. Nonetheless, it seems to always point to this sentence: `loss.backward()`.

I'm running the code over GPU and have the paid subscription to Colab Pro.

Does anybody have faced this issue? I read somewhere that this seems to be a problem of the GPU running out of memory, however, can't say that for sure given the error messages I'm receiving.

Answer (score 0):

Well, It took a while but I managed to find the source of this problem myself. Some other posts mentioned this could be a GPU memory issue so I tried to minimize the memory usage as much as possible. Though this was good for my code, it didn't solve the problem.
Others talked about switching to CPU and running the script to get a better error message (which I did and took forever). Running my script with CPU gave the error of binary cross entropy not receiving inputs in the zero to one interval. This was clearly not the problem since those inputs can from a sigmoid function.

Finally, I recall the last thing I changed before my script started behaving like this and I found out that it was because of the learning rate. When I ran my training with a learning rate of 0.001, everything was fine. I switched it to 0.02 (20 times higher) and then I started receiving this execution errors at random. Switching back to the smaller learning rate solved the problem immediately. No more GPU errors and now I'm happy.

So, if you have this issue, you my take a look to the learning rate and hopefully will help you.